# Class proper not assigned in swift

Tags: request, swift2, handler, assign

I'm doing a practice, and find my class property(adNames) can't be assigned. But it can be assigned outside(the place where I comment out). Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class AdTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var adNames: [JSON]?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://codewithchris.com/code/afsample.json").responseJSON { (Response) -> Void in

            if let value = Response.result.value{

                let json = JSON(value)
                print(json["secondkey"].arrayValue) //["item1","item2","item3"] 
                self.adNames = json["secondkey"].arrayValue
            }
        }
//        self.adNames = ["item1", "item2", "item3"]
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if let names = adNames {
            return names.count
        }
        return 0
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        ...
    }

}
```

Can anybody tell me the reason? Thanks!

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: the the adNames are not assigned to ["item1", "item2", "item3"] so that the  names.count in the tableview() is 0

Comment: Maybe include the json you're getting as text. Do you know that `self.adNames` is not nil? Maybe include `print(json["secondarykey"])`

Comment: print(json["secondarykey"]) works well, I can print(json["secondarykey"].arrayValue) and get ["item1","item2","item3"].  just updated the code, and you can see the new added print

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Alamofire request runs in the background. Meanwhile, your tableView wants to display and calls numberOfRowsInSection. By this time, Alamofire has not finished its work, so adnames hasn't been set.

You need to refresh the tableView with `reloadData()` after adNames is set. i.e.

```
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://codewithchris.com/code/afsample.json").responseJSON { (Response) -> Void in
        if let value = Response.result.value{
            let json = JSON(value)
            self.adNames = json["secondkey"].arrayValue
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Then the tableView will refresh and re-call numberOfRowsInSection, and at this time, adNames will not be nil.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing self inside a closure which is passed to the request call. Use capture lists inside the closure to hold the references to the self object.

`[weak self] (Response)` -> Void in (in this case you have to use `self?` to access the self instance)
...

or `[unowned self] (Response) -> Void in`

If you are sure that the object will be present after the request call completes.

Comment: Just tried but not work... maybe it's not a reference issue, because it works if I hard coded an array outside the closure.

Comment: I would check Michael and Unheilig's answers. Could be incorrect use of keys as Unheilig mentioned or the fact that the table is not reloaded after the request call completes.

Comment: Yes, Michael's solution works. The table is not reloaded.